# how to save a variable at each iteration of a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, netcdf, python-xarray

I have written a for loop for computing sample rolling average for my NetCDF file witch is (73, 10000, 10000) and it computes the rolling average for 25 subtitles with dimension (73, 2000, 2000), and I want to save this vh_sub_roll at each iteration to achieve an ultimate corrected NetCDF file which is also (73, 10000, 10000), but I don't know how to do it. someone can help with this.

```
 vh = xarray.open_dataset('D:/kfakheri_data/thesis/Netcdf_files/all/ultimate_netcdf_VH.nc')
 maxr = 5
 # subtile numbers help to check individual parts of the array, if necessary. 1=upper right, 
 25=lower left corner
 subtile = 1
 for rx in range(maxr):
      for ry in range(maxr):
         x1 = rx*2000
         x2 = rx*2000+2000-1
         y1 = ry*2000+2000-1
         y2 = ry*2000
         print(x1, x2, y2, y1)
         # slice entire tile into 2000x2000 pixels
         vh_sub = vh.sel(x=slice(x1, x2), y=slice(y1, y2))
         # apply rolling average: average over 5 timestamps (centered around the timestamp of 
         interest), if less than
      
         vh_sub_roll = vh_sub['VH_gaussian'].rolling(dim={'time': 5}, min_periods=2, 
         center=True).mean()
         subtile += 1
```